# Django TypeError

Tags: python, django

I get an error with model like this:

```
class Project(models.Model):  # Should Rename to Project Name
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    frequency = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    related_tests = models.ManyToManyField(TestType)
    creation_date = models.DateField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.creation_date = datetime.date.today()

Error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Project'
```

When I comment out,

```
    creation_date = models.DateField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.creation_date = datetime.date.today()
```

...the code works.

My question is, what is prompting the error?

Comment: Don't just post the final error message.  Post the entire error traceback, so we can see _what line of code_ caused the error.

Comment: When submitting a question like this, it's helpful to see a) the version of python being used, b) the version of django being used, c) all the code involved (I don't see how you get that error without actually trying to create a Project object).

Comment: See [MCVE] for advice on posting a problem.

Comment: Thanks guys. Regarding why I did not post the entire traceback, I knew problem was in that those lines of code and those alone so there was no reason to bother people with entire traceback. The answer below pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass `self` to `__init__` with `super`:

```
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or in python 2, you should do:

```
super(Project, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I missed that! Think you've found it.